# Can I store Dark Elixir Clan War winnings if don't have a Dark Elixir storage?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm in a Clan War and I see a little mini dark elixir storage at the top of my Clan Castle, but I don't have an actual dark elixir storage.  Will the dark elixir stay in the Clan Castle until I can claim it?

Comment: But for some reason i only see it when i click info on my clan castle -p.s im upgrading it to lvl 2 right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loot won in a Clan War is automatically stored in the Clan Castle at the end of every war. This includes Dark Elixir. War loot cannot be spent until it has been collected, and if you collect the loot without a Dark Elixir Storage you will lose it.

The Dark Elixir will stay in your Clan Castle until you collect it, or until its raided. I recommend you read this [page from the wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Castle) which gives you more detailed information on Clan Castles.

The miniature gold, elixir and dark elixir storages on top of the clan castle represent where the war loot is stored after a war has ended. You can see these in the following picture of a level 2 Clan Castle:

[image: Level 2 Clan Castle]

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Castle)

Comment: From the wiki: "The miniature Dark Elixir Storage on top of the Clan Castle will not show up until you have built a regular Dark Elixir Storage (nor will the "War Dark Elixir" amount be shown in the Info screen)."

Answer (score 1):

The Dark Elixir will stay in your Clan Castle until you are raided. It will not go away, and if you win Dark Elixir in your Clan Castle the next war, the Dark Elixir will only accumulate until collected. In other words, it won't disappear or be wasted unless you are raided or try to collect it without a Dark Elixir Storage

Answer (score 0):

The Clan Castle houses any reinforcement troops sent by your clanmates. Bonus loot won in Clan Wars is automatically stored in the Clan Castle at the end of every war."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you don't have a DE storage, you can't get DE from war loot, even if you win the war. This is because there is literally nowhere for your base to store the Dark Elixir. Your Clan Castle loot after the war just shows the Gold and Elixir you won, not DE. Happened to me more than once.